# Convert diff to markdown with strikeout?

Tags: algorithm, diff, markdown

I'd like to convert the output of `diff` (on a Markdown file) to
Markdown with `<strike>` and `<em>` tags, so that I can see what has
been removed from or added to a new version of a document.  (This kind of
treatment is very common for legal documents.)

Example of hoped-for output:

> *Why do we*<strike>We</strike> study programming languages*?* <strike>not</strike>*Not* in order to ...

One of the many
difficulties is that diff's output is line-oriented, where I want to
see differences in individual words.  Does anyone have suggestions as
to what algorithm to use, or what software to build on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [wdiff](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/).  It already does the word-by-word comparison you're looking for; converting its output to markdown should take just a few simple regular expressions.

For example:

```
$ cat foo
Why do we study programming languages?  Not in order to
$ cat bar
We study programming languages not in order to
$ wdiff foo bar
[-Why do we-]{+We+} study programming [-languages?  Not-] {+languages not+} in order to
$ wdiff foo bar | sed 's|\[-|<em>|g;s|-]|</em>|g;s|{+|<strike>|g;s|+}|</strike>|g'
<em>Why do we</em><strike>We</strike> study programming <em>languages?  Not</em> <strike>languages not</strike> in order to
```

Edit: Actually, wdiff has some options that make it even easier:

```
$ wdiff -w '<em>' -x '</em>' -y '<strike>' -z '</strike>' foo bar
<em>Why do we</em><strike>We</strike> study programming <em>languages?  Not</em> <strike>languages not</strike> in order to
```

Answer (score 7):

Use **[Markdown-Diff](http://netj.github.io/markdown-diff/#an-example/markdown-diff)** to have the word diff annotated to your original document.  It formats `wdiff` or `git --word-diff`'s output in Markdown, so you can use your favorite Markdown previewer or compiler to review changes. (Markdown-Diff was written by myself, inspired by [Adam Rosenfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384393/390044).)

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify the target platform, but assuming if you are using .NET you should definitely check out this article on CodeProject
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx

The diff engine performs comparison and return you the logical object which can apply your own visual display formatting to it. I have used it in several projects one of which was a web based text comparison and we were able to introduced all those markup like you wanted above. I have also extend the engine with new classes to do custom line type comparisons.