# Creating a easy to read PDF of a diff file

Tags: diff, markdown

What is the best way to create a easy-to-read PDF that contains a colorized diff from git history? The diff is based on one markdown file.

Do note: I'm already able to generate the .diff I need I just need to transpose it to a pretty PDF.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See also [Convert diff to markdown with strikeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384384/convert-diff-to-markdown-with-strikeout)

Answer (score 4):

The best thing I've found so far is [pretty-diff](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/pretty-diff). It generates a half-way-decent pdf of what we need. I'll edit this response if I find anything better.